# Subtract one date from another and get int

Tags: python, django

How can I subtract on datefield from another and get result in integer?

Like 11.05.2015-10.05.2015 will return 1

I tried 
`entry.start_devation= each.start_on_fact - timedelta(days=data.calendar_start)`

Answer (score 0):

Take the difference between two dates, which is a `timedelta`, and ask for the `days` attribute of that `timedelta`.